# Search calendarview events by title and attendee email with Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am trying to implement a search on top of the Microsoft Graph calendarview API to provide feature parity with Google Calendar search, where the search term will return results with a matching event subject, or attendee name/email.

I am able to implement subject search with

`$filter=contains(subject, '<query'>)`

however, I have been unable to figure out how to return results with matching attendee name/email.

I have tried

`$filter=contains(subject, '<term>') OR attendees/any(a: contains(a/emailAddress/address, '<term>'))`

but get the error:

> The query filter contains one or more invalid nodes.

I tried using eq instead

`$filter=contains(subject, '<term>') OR attendees/any(a: a/emailAddress/address eq '<term>')`

but then get the error:

> An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.

I also tried using

`$search="<term>"`

this returns no error, but doesn't filter the results at all.

Is it possible to search for calendar events with matching title or attendee, using this, or another, api?

Answer (score 0):

According [this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/1771?msclkid=fb1d8df8b7fb11ec8238d3ee26457d27#issuecomment-410301969) comment Graph API doesn't support drilling down multiple levels of relationships.